# Restricting fields from being set in Sails.js Model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, sails.js, waterline

So I have a model with some fields like so:

```
// ...
slug: {
  type: 'string',
  required: true,
  alphanumeric: true,
  minLength: 3,
  maxLength: 16
},
loggedinAt: 'date',
// ...
```

I'm using the Sails blueprint structure so it automatically maps everything. However, sometimes I have fields like `loggedinAt` which are strictly internal and I don't want them to be able to be set by the user.

As it stands if I make a post requests with the `loggedinAt` field it will set it. How can I restrict this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a policy to restrict this behavior.  In **api/policies/restrictUserCreate.js**:

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {

    // Check for the "loggedInAt" field in the request
    if (req.param('loggedInAt')) {
       return res.badRequest("Nuh uh, you can't set that!");
    }

    return next();

}
```

or, to just ignore certain fields (Sails v0.10.x only), use the *blacklist*:

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {

    // Make sure blacklist object exists, and use existing one if possible,
    // since this policy could be chained
    req.options.values = req.options.values || {};
    req.options.values.blacklist = req.options.values.blacklist || [];
    // Add restricted fields to the blacklist
    req.options.values.blacklist.push('loggedinAt');
    return next();

}
```

Then in **config/policies.js**:

```
// Assuming your controller is "UserController"
UserController: {
    create: "restrictUserCreate"
}
```

Comment: That seems like a bit of work to do for each param, perhaps better phrasing is to just ignore it. For instance if I just set something like "blahb=blah" there is no effect.

Comment: Ah, ok.  Added info to my answer about the blacklist in Sails v0.10.x.  In v0.9.x, you'd have to just override the "create" action in your controller.

Comment: Came across this [here](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/352) which is more of what I'm looking for, however it only works in the bleeding edge version at 0.10.x.

Comment: Deleting items from `req.params` in a policy is not reliable, since Sails binds the params separately to each middleware.  That's why `req.options` was invented.  The blacklist should work with any release of v0.10.x.

Comment: My `req.options` is coming up `undefined`...?

Comment: Hm, the code above works for me.  You're using it in a policy?